# Thrust Gathering/Filtering

Tags: cuda, thrust

What I am trying to do is create a filter on a vector so it removes elements that do not pass a predicate test; but not too sure how I go about it.

I evaluate each element in my inputer vector against the predicate, for example in my code the is_even functor, in a device_vector vector. It is true if it passes the test and false if it's not.

Now I am stuck because I now have this bool vector and I want to gather the elements that passed this predicate test. I store it in a bool vector because I want to keep the result to filter other vectors.

```
#include ...

template<typename T>
struct is_even : thrust::unary_function<T, bool>
{
    __host__ __device__
    bool operator()(const T &x)
    {
        return (x%2)==0;
    }
};

int main(void)
{
    std::cout << "Loading test!" << std::endl;
    const int N = 1000000;
    thrust::device_vector<int> col1(N);
    thrust::device_vector<float> col2(N, 1); 
    thrust::sequence(col1.begin(), col1.end());

    thrust::device_vector<bool> filter(N);
    thrust::transform(col1.begin(), col1.end(), filter.begin(), is_even<int>());

    // filter col1 and col2 based on filter

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking.  What are the inputs and desired outputs?  Describe your filtering operation.   Have you tried anything?  What specifically is not working?  Are you getting a compile error or an error when you run the code?  The code you have shown compiles correctly for me.

Comment: Ok, I edited so hopefully it should be more clearer.

Comment: So you just want to know how to gather the elements of `col1` for which `is_even` is true?

Comment: Yes, but based on the filter vector instead of using copy_if. What I am trying to achieve is to filter a set of vectors (col1,col2... coln) based on a predicate against col1; to emulate a SQL where filter; so ideally it should filter all columns in one go rather than doing them individually.

Comment: Also, it should be a copy to keep the original data untouched.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Within the [stream compaction group](https://nvidia.github.io/cccl/thrust/api/groups/group__stream__compaction.html) you may be interested in `thrust::copy_if`

We can select the even elements into a new vector directly using your defined predicate without making an intermediate `filter` vector:

```
thrust::copy_if(col1.begin(), col1.end(), result.begin(), is_even<int>());
```

(`result` should be a vector of identical type to `col1`, and already defined to be a length equal to or greater than `col1`, since it's unknown how many elements will pass the predicate test.)

If you want to work off of the `filter` vector you have created, use the [stencil version](http://thrust.github.io/doc/group__stream__compaction.html#ga36d9d6ed8e17b442c1fd8dc40bd515d5) of `copy_if` instead.

Here's a worked example using the stencil method based on your comments:

```
$ cat t267.cu
#include <iostream>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/sequence.h>
#include <thrust/transform.h>
#include <thrust/copy.h>

template<typename T>
struct is_even : thrust::unary_function<T, bool>
{
    __host__ __device__
    bool operator()(const T &x)
    {
        return (x%2)==0;
    }
};


struct is_true : thrust::unary_function<bool, bool>
{
    __host__ __device__
    bool operator()(const bool &x)
    {
        return x;
    }
};

int main(void)
{
    std::cout << "Loading test!" << std::endl;
    const int N = 1000000;
    thrust::device_vector<int> col1(N);
    thrust::device_vector<float> col2(N, 1);
    thrust::sequence(col1.begin(), col1.end());

    thrust::device_vector<bool> filter(N);
    thrust::device_vector<int> result(N);
    thrust::transform(col1.begin(), col1.end(), filter.begin(), is_even<int>());
    // filter col1 based on filter
    thrust::device_vector<int>::iterator end = thrust::copy_if(col1.begin(), col1.end(), filter.begin(), result.begin(), is_true());
    int len = end - result.begin();
    thrust::host_vector<int> h_result(len);
    thrust::copy_n(result.begin(), len, h_result.begin());
    thrust::copy_n(h_result.begin(), 10, std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, "\n"));


    return 0;
}
$ nvcc -arch=sm_20 -o t267 t267.cu
$ ./t267
Loading test!
0
2
4
6
8
10
12
14
16
18
$
```

Comment: Is it possible to copy multiple streams in one call using a stencil? I.e. filter multiple column vectors in one linear scan based on the stencil from applying the predicate against col1.

Comment: I'd suggest you ask it as a new SO question.  Most thrust operations take only single vectors, not arrays of vectors.  You could use various methods to concatenate your column vectors (and perhaps also replicate your filter vector) and do it all in one operation, but it will also generate one vector for output, which will be confusing.

Comment: @user2991422 Use a `zip_iterator` to filter multiple arrays at once.